# Batch log looping echo

Tags: loops, batch-file, logging, echo, psexec

My batch file stops and starts a service via psexec and logs the results to a txt file.  The batch functions as intended but the log file is only writing the first token from the file which psexec is referencing.  How can I ensure the log is iterating with the loop?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (IP_LIST.txt) do call :action %%a

:action
psexec \\@IP_LIST.txt -u admin -p password cmd /c "net stop spooler && net start spooler && echo [%date%, %time%] - Restarted service on %1 && echo ===========================================" >> LOG.txt
```

Here is what the log file looks like:

> ```
> The spooler service is stopping. The spooler service was stopped successfully.
>
> The spooler service is starting. The spooler service was started successfully.
>
> [Wed 06/20/2018, 12:24:30.61] - Restarted spooler service on
> 192.168.0.1
>
> ===========================================  The spooler service is stopping. The spooler service was stopped successfully.
>
> The spooler service is starting. The spooler service was started successfully.
>
> [Wed 06/20/2018, 12:24:30.61] - Restarted spooler service on
> 192.168.0.1 
> ===========================================
> ```

The file `IP_LIST.txt` contains 1 IP per line with no additional data.

Comment: Redirect the output from `NET.exe` to the `NUL` device if you don't want that output in your log file.

Comment: Your existing code should write everything to the log file because you are using the `>>` operator to append to the file.  You should put a `GOTO :EOF` before your `:action` label otherwise it will try and execute a second time.

Comment: I want the output, it's just not giving me exactly what I want.  It's not incrementing the IP and time even though the loop is incrementing through the file being pushed against net.exe.

Comment: Your code also makes no sense.  There is no need for the `FOR` command if you are feeding `PSEXEC` the ip list file.  If you are going to use the `FOR` command then your psexec command should look like: `PSEXEC \\%1 .......`

Comment: So essentially the way your code is setup it will run psexec n^2.  If you have 10 ip addresses in your file.  It will run psexec 100 times.

Comment: I thought the FOR command would iterate but psexec is iterating through the file.  I understand.  Regardless it functions as intended with or without the for command.  Pointing that out was no help whatsoever.

Comment: Modifying the code to remove the FOR loop still does not resolve the issue at hand.

Comment: Where in any of my comments did I tell you to remove the `FOR` command?  I said if you are going to use the `FOR` command then you need to run psexec like this: `psexec \\%1.......`

Comment: You never explicitly told me to.  You noted that there's no need for it if I'm iterating psexec against a list.  So I either eliminate the for loop and reference the txt file to iterate in the psexec command or keep the for loop and reference the psexec command to a variable in the loop.  Correct?

Comment: If you are going to use the command line argument for the `ECHO` you have to use the command line argument with the `PSEXEC` command.  Period.

Comment: @Squashman I see my fault and now understand.  This is my second day working with batch files so I was a bit confused.  Really over thought this one.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the command line argument with PSEXEC.

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (IP_LIST.txt) do call :action %%a

GOTO :EOF
:action
psexec \\%1 -u admin -p password cmd /c "net stop spooler && net start spooler && echo [%date%, %time%] - Restarted service on %1 && echo ===========================================" >> LOG.txt
```